# HashMap delete entry AND position

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm just working with `HashMaps` and now it pops up a question I actually can't answer by myself...

In my HashMap there are some entries. I'm now searching through all the entries for a certain value. If that value is found It delete it using `hashmap.remove();`. But I don't "only" want to delete the entry but the whole "position" of the HashMap so that there is no blank space between it. In the end the HashMap shouldn't have any value anymore (I think it will be null then, won't it?)

Is there any possible way to do so?

That's what I got so far but it only deletes the entry not the whole position...

```
for (Entry<Integer, String> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue().contains("EnterStringHere")) {
        myMap.remove(entry);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your code, especially the part *searching through all the entries for a certain value.*

Comment: Can you share your existing code please?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you want the HashMap to use fewer buckets when entries are deleted? Why do you care?

Comment: ... and why do you want the hashmap to get shorter?

Comment: That's what I got so far but it only deletes the entry not the whole position...
for (Entry<Integer, String> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
if (entry.getValue().contains("EnterStringHere")) {
myMap.remove(entry);
}}

Comment: Define what you mean by "delete the position". What happens, and what would you want to happen instead? HashMaps don't have "positions", so it's quite hard to understand what you mean. Also, your code will lead to ConcurrentModificationException. Use the iterator to remove the entry.

Comment: This is the under-lying functionality of the Map, I smell something here.

Comment: Because after a certain time I need to check if the HashMap is empty. But another answer seems to get the hint I needed. If I delete the value the entry will be null? Can i do a check if every entry is null easily or do i have to iterate over every entry again?

Comment: why not just check the size?

Comment: removing an entry from a map decreases its size, obviously. If you remove all the entries, the map will be empty.

Comment: JB Nizet: I just checked it and thats not true... If I delete an entry the size is still the same... but the delete entry holds null now.

Comment: Post a complete runnable test case reproducing the problem.

Comment: @Shijury you cannot delete an entry from a Map it expects a key also if you try to modify a map structurally by removing elements while iterating then you will get ConcurrentModification Exception. Please check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong

```
for (Entry<Integer, String> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
if (entry.getValue().contains("EnterStringHere")) {
    myMap.remove(entry); // you should pass the key to remove
   }
 }
```

But you can't use this way to remove element. You will get `ConcurrentModificationException`.

You can try this way using `iterator` to remove element while iterating.

```
 Map<Integer,String> map=new HashMap<>();
 map.put(1,"EnterStringHere");
 map.put(2,"hi");
 map.put(3,"EnterStringHere");
 Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer,String>> iterator=map.entrySet().iterator();
 while (iterator.hasNext()){
    Map.Entry<Integer,String> entry=iterator.next();
        if(entry.getValue().equals("EnterStringHere")){
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
 System.out.println(map);
```

Out put:

```
 {2=hi}
```

You really need to see [HashMap#remove()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove the entry object from a Map. The remove method expects key.

Instead you can try the below:-

```
Iterator<Entry<Integer, String>> itr = myMap.entrySet().iterator();

        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            Entry<Integer, String> entry = itr.next();
            if (entry.getValue().contains("EnterStringHere")) 
            { 
                itr.remove(); 
            }
        }
```

Also you cannot directly structurally modify a Map while iterating else you will get ConcurrentModification Exception. To prevent this you need to delete using the remove method on the iterator as shown in above code.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you got a `Map<Key,Value>` size of `10` and you want to remove `8`th key value pair in current `Map`. What happen is `Map` become the size of `9` and there will be another key value pair in `8`th position.

You can't to beyond that with `remove()`. You can't remove the position.

But when you use `Map.get(removed_key)` you will get `null` since there is no key there now.

Eg:

```
Map<String,Integer> map=new HashMap<>();
map.put("a",1);
map.put("b",2);
map.put("c", 3);
System.out.println("size of the map "+map.size() +" map is "+map);
map.remove("b");
System.out.println("size of the map "+map.size() +" map is "+map);
System.out.println(map.get("b"));
```

Out put:

```
size of the map 3 map is {b=2, c=3, a=1}
size of the map 2 map is {c=3, a=1}
null // you are getting null since there is no key "b"
```

Adding this to provide answer to your comment,If you want to check whether map is empty. simply use  `map.isEmpty()`

Answer (score 0):

Understanding how `HashMap` works here [Link](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-hashmap-works-in-java.html).
Also see java doc here [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

If you want to set pack your hashmap try to check size of the map then delete one then check size again for example.

```
hashmap.size();        => 10
hashmap.remove(obj);
hashmap.size()         => 9
```

this means the hashmap is packed and will not have any empty entry. At the end hashmap will automatically will not contain any value in it

Answer (score 0):

> Because after a certain time I need to check if the HashMap is empty. But another answer seems to get the hint I needed. If I delete the value the entry will be null?  Can i do a check if every entry is null easily or do i have to iterate over every entry again?

You do not delete a value from a Map you delete a mapping. this code does not delete any thing:

```
myMap.remove(entry);
```

because you pass the entry object, you need to pass the key of the mapping on order to delete it, see [Map.html#remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) docs.

thus

```
myMap.remove(entry.getkey());
```

However with the current approach you will run in `ConcurrentModificationException`. If it didnt till now it's just because your code didn't delete anything, *because you pass the entry object*

If you delete the mapping from the map, that mapping will no longer exist in the map. Whether the bucket is `null` or not is implementation detail, but when you query a mapping that was deleted using the given key you'll [get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get-java.lang.Object-) `null` as return value. If you add another mapping with the same key you will get taht mapping again.

You can check if a map is empty using [Map#isEmpty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#isEmpty--), thus you dont need to check if every entry is null or iterate over the whole map to do so.

You can check if a map contain a mapping for a key using [Map.#containsKey](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-)

You can check if a map caintains at least one mapping for a value using [Map#containsValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsValue-java.lang.Object-)

the correct way to delete etriey from a map while iteration it to use an `iterator`

```
Iterator<Entry<Integer, String>> iterator = myMap.entrySet().iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    Entry<Integer, String> entry = iterator.next();
    if (entry.getValue().contains("foo")) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Since you have `Map<Integer, String>` I assume that the *position* you mean is the integer key, where you do something like `myMap.put(1, ".")`, `myMap.put(2, "..")`, `myMap.put(3, "...")` and so on. In that case if you remove the mapping for the key `1` for example, the postion, i.e the mapping `{1 : "."}` will no longer exist in the map.

Answer (score -1):

OK I got a codeable example that's pretty easy.

```
public class TestingThingsOut {

public static void main(String [] args) {
    HashMap<Integer, String> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    myMap.put(123, "hello");
    myMap.put(234, "Bye");
    myMap.put(789, "asdf");

    System.out.println(myMap); // it says:
                                  {789=asdf, 234=Bye, 123=hello}

    System.out.println(myMap.size()); // it says: "3"

    for (Entry<Integer, String> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().contains("hello")) {
            myMap.remove(entry);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(myMap); // it says:
                                  {789=asdf, 234=Bye, 123=hello}

    System.out.println(myMap.size()); // it says: "3" again
}
```

}

Comment: You can't use for-each to remove element. You will get ConcurrentModificationException. What you are doing here is wrong

Comment: @Shijury this solution also doesnot remove the element. Please check my answer below

Comment: In this code nothing happen. If you want to remove element from `Map`. You should call `map.remove(key)`. Clare fully read my both answers

Comment: you should iterate the `keySet` not the `entrySet` to get the exception

Comment: This is not an answer to this question. You can edit your question to provide what you have tried.